# How Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution is related to phase space?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-space

Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution give us the probability of particle to have a speed between $u$ and $u+du$.

Can we interpret this distribution as how many times a specific speed is found in the phase space?

Lets assume that we have a system of $n$ particles with total energy $E$ and there are $Ω$ microstates. Each microstate will be characterized by the particles's speeds, so for microstate $i$ we have $(u_{1i}, u_{2i}, \ldots, u_{ni})$ (and same for other microstates).

Can we calculate the probability that a particle will have speed between $u$ and $u+du$ by finding the number of times speed between $u$ and $u+du$ appears in the phase space (i.e. microstates compatible with the given energy) and dividing by $n\cdotΩ$?

Is this approach consistent with the interpretation of the distribution? I mean the distribution doesn't distinguishes between particle $1$ and particle $2$ whereas in phase space the maybe particle $2$ never takes the value $u$ (assuming distinguishable particles).

**Edit** Suppose that we monitor the speed of a specific particle (assuming distinguishable particles and for simplicity the system is composed of $2$ particles). If we record its speed many times is it necessary that it will follow the distribution? I would say yes only if for every microstate, e.g. $i=(30, 40)$, we can generate a new microstate as $j=(40, 30)$.

Is my reasoning correct? Are there any cases that a specific particle is not allowed to take a specific value of speed?

Comment: In the monatomic, ideal gas, and if we interpret the momentum as velocityxmass as in the classical, nonrelativistic mechanics, yes.